# UTP CCA vs UTP CU cables

Tags: arduino

I need to transfer data over about 20m from a DS18B20 to a Arduino board, I was wondering if I could use the much cheaper CCA cable?

Also can you please inform me in which cases must I go for the CU cable. The differences between the two types are obvious but I still do not know in which cases I should use CU type. I have found some information in which is stated that CU, due to it's lower resistance, is required in case the load is draining significant current. What about frequency?

Comment: You might have problems soldering CCA cable if the CC gets damaged. Also, can you afford the voltage drop when the CCA cable has about 55% greater resistance (ref: [Application Note: Copper Clad Aluminum(CCA) Cables](http://www.flukenetworks.com/content/application-note-copper-clad-aluminum-cables)) than copper cable?

Answer (score 1):

DS18B20 digital thermometer has maximum supply current of 1.5mA. You can use CCA cable as long as total loop resistance ( 20m + 20m ) of the cable is not greater than say 60-80 ohms. You should also pay attention to the capacitance of the data line. Regardless of the cable used it will form low pass filter to your data.